# DSBULK is showing authorization error, however the load is completing without any failed erros

Tags: cassandra, datastax, dsbulk

I am executing DSBULK, it actually runs and completes. In the output I do not see any failed records, but I see the below error message. Is this because the permissions_validity_in_ms is set to 2000 ms. Should it be increased?

```
com.datastax.oss.driver.api.core.servererrors.UnauthorizedException: Unable to perform authorization of permissions: Unable to perform authorization of super-user permission: Operation timed out - received only 0 responses.
```